# Display "$xx.90" instead of "$xx.9" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, currency

When I use p=10000 ,r=15 and n=60 in the below ...

```
var x = parseFloat((Math.round(r/12/100*p/(1-Math.pow(1+ +(r/12/100),-n))*100)/100).toFixed(2));
```

x = `237.9` instead of `237.90`.

If the combo of p, r and n result in a number that is not $xx.x", then the code snippet works fine ...ie. formats to 2 decimal places.

But why is it displaying 237.9 instead of 237.90?

Comment: Hi Barmar -- can you please refer me to the responses to the identical question? Thanks

Comment: Click on the link.

Comment: @Barmar The problem here isn't wrong usage of `toFixed` (as N [does indeed mean exactly N decimal digits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)), it's that the result is converted back into a float.

Comment: @Frxstrem I've reopened the question, you should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `number.toFixed(2)`, you do indeed get a string representation of the number with two decimal digits:

```
var number = 237.9;
number.toFixed(2);             // '237.90'
```

However, when you then use `parseFloat` on this, you convert it *back* to a number again; since a number does not contain information about the number of zeros to display, the last zero is dropped as it is printed:

```
parseFloat(number.toFixed(2)); // 237.9
```

To avoid this, simply don't convert your string back into a float, but use it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = parseFloat((Math.round(r/12/100*p/(1-Math.pow(1+ +(r/12/100),-n))*100)/100)).toFixed(2);
```

```js
p=10000,r=15, n=60;

var x = parseFloat((Math.round(r/12/100*p/(1-Math.pow(1+ +(r/12/100),-n))*100)/100)).toFixed(2);

console.log(x)
```

Add toFixed after all operations. You need string, basically...